# How to change the [disabled] property of an Angular object

Tags: html, asp.net, angular

I would like to change the [disabled] property of the "app-box-ceding-company-definition" object; in the ts the property is set to true but I would like to change its value based on the outcome of a condition.

condition: selectrow.status == "01" => disabled = true

selectrow.status == "02" => disabled = false

here the statement:

```
<div>
<div style="float:left"><span><dx-text-box id="text_box" [ngStyle]="{'color': disabled ? 'darkgray': '' }" [disabled]="true" [(value)]="textValue" class="TextBox_width_box" style="opacity:0.9"></dx-text-box></span></div>
<div style="float:left"><button class="buttonstyle btnChoose" id="box-ceding-company-definition.btnChoose" [ngStyle]="{'color': disabled ? 'darkgray': '' }" (click)="clearValues()">X</button></div>
<div style="float:left"><button class="buttonstyle btnClear" id="box-ceding-company-definition.btnClear" [ngStyle]="{'color': disabled ? 'darkgray': '' }" (click)="showPopup()">...</button></div>
```

here where I want to insert the condition (disabled="true"):

```
<div class="right_half">
        <div class="divRowCellLabel" *ngIf="selectedAgreement.cateSector != 'AC'"><label>{{'agreement_tab_definition_lbl_ceding_company'  | translate}}</label></div>
        <div class="divRowCellLabel" *ngIf="selectedAgreement.cateSector == 'AC'"><label>{{'agreement_tab_definition_lbl_ceding_company_sotto'  | translate}}</label></div>
        <div class="divRowCellFieldLarger"> <app-box-ceding-company-definition id="definition-tab-agreement.defiCedingComp" [textValue]="selectedAgreement.defiCedingComp" class="largerFields" (notifyPopup)="receiveEmitPopup($event)" disabled="true" (emitFullValue)="recieveCedingCompany($event)"></app-box-ceding-company-definition>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put a fixed [disabled]="true" . Try replace true to your condition.

```
[disabled]="selectrow.status == '01'" // if true disable ON
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't work

Comment: put the error here. pls. First question is 'app-box-ceding-company-definition'  has property disable?? if not you need ngif

Comment: as you can see from the declaration of the object [disabled] it is true, so I would like to make it variable.
I'm not getting any errors, I just can't change the status of [disabled] to false.
I tried to use the "ngif" in the html page,
[Disabled] = "ngif =" selectrow.status == '01' "".
I have tried this and other similar solutions but it still does not change the status of [disabled]

Comment: i cant understand why not. A example with button https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qojs8j?file=src/app/app.component.html".